# Passport.js local strategy WITHOUT mongoose

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to find resources about the most simple login with passport for a node app. I mean, using:

middleware:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.use(express.static('public'));
```

passport:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done({ id: id, nickname: "test"})
});


    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {
        console.log("test");
          if (username === 'username') {
              return done(null, { name: "test", id: '1234'});
          } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect cred.' });
          }
      })
    )
```

and redirection:

```
    app.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', { 
          successRedirect: '/index.html',
          failureRedirect: '/login'
     })
    );
```

my app structure:

```
/app.js
/public/index.html
/public/login.html
```

And that's it. the Web is full of the same examples of Mongoose with plugins, everyone simply copy-pasting from each other.

The point is that I would like, later on, to insert my own code ti the LocalStrategy code (would probably used LDAP).

Currently, instead of redirecting to /index.html with the page created in the public folder, I just receive `[object Object]` on index.html.

Comment: Your code is missing `passport.serializeUser/deserializeUser`. After adding those, it works just fine (although `failureRedirect` points to a non-existent URL).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it (just edit the question). So still, my success redirect is not working as expected /:

Comment: So it's actually the request to `/index.html` that's causing the issue, and not so much the `POST` to `/login`? I don't see how a request to `/index.html` can fail.

Comment: You're right, the login mechanism works, but the redirection is not. If I send a request to /index.html from the browser, it simply goes there without even using passport, which is lame. I'll solve that later. but as I POST to /login, the redirection opens index.html, but NOT the one on the public folder, just a plain text with [Object object]. So weird.

Comment: Let me guess: you're requesting `POST /login` through an XHR/AJAX/fetch request?

Comment: Yes, i'm using a standard form:  `<form action="/login" method="post">`

Comment: If it's a regular form submission, it doesn't make any sense. There isn't any route handler in the code you're showing that could generate that `[object Object]` response.

Comment: Well, the `POST /login` really goes the the passport handler, and after it succeeds (`return done(null, { name: "test", id: '1234'});`), there is redirection and `[Object object]` is printed both the the console and the browser. That's what drive me nuts- i'm trying to implement to mist basic scenario and receive errors.
It's like there's a complete ignore of the `express.static('public')` declaration.

Comment: The server console is showing `[object Object]`?

Comment: Yes. both the server console and the html document.

Comment: And you are absolutely 100% sure that the code that you're posting is the actual code that you're using, and nothing more (apart from a few `require()` statements)?

Comment: well of course. It is the code i'm using, without the 'require' statements. very minimalistic.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, and I also don't see any reason why `[object Object]` is being logged to console (none of the modules you use would do that, and your code obviously doesn't either). Perhaps it's time to remove `./node_modules` and reinstall all dependencies.

Comment: done that. well I'll keep digging. thanks for reaching out! will update.

Comment: Try running your app in debug mode: `env DEBUG=* node app.js` (or the Windows-equivalent, if you're using that)

Answer (score 3):

Your `passport.deserializeUser()` is incorrect:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done({ id: id, nickname: "test"})
});
```

It's passing the "user" object as first argument to `done`, which is reserved for errors. This causes Express to render an error page where it tries to stringify the error, resulting in `[object Object]`.

Try this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done(null, { id: id, nickname: "test"})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue! the redirection didn't work, so I looked back up and noticed that the express.static mw was set AFTER the passport initialize(), and not BEFORE. I just moved it up to the top and.. rainbows

Comment: That's, um, interesting. It works just fine for me that way (`express.static()` after `passport.initialize()`, like in the code you posted).

Comment: I still get the error on the console, on both cases. but the redirection works only if I move the the `static` to the start.
I'm using express 4.15.2, passport 0.3.2 and node 7.9.0.

Comment: @Chen - It would be more heplful if you posted your entire solution here